# \rput for RTL language

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pspicture

How can i use `\rput` for farsi?
for example, I write this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}(0, 0)
\psset{unit=1cm}
 \rput(10,0){حالت چطوره؟ }
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and I get:

```
چطوره؟ حالت
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead  put this code into a minimal compilable document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own `\RPut`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout.ttf}
\def\RPut(#1)#2{\rput(#1){\rl{#2}}}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{pspicture}(0, 0)
    \psset{unit=1cm}
    \RPut(10,0){حالت چطوره؟ }
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the text into an `\rl` macro. (Font is different in the image, as I don't have your font installed.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.5]{IRYakout}
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}(0, 0)
\psset{unit=1cm}
 \rput(10,0){\rl{حالت چطوره؟ }}
 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]